# How to make an image from a Docker container

Tags: docker

I'm following a tutorial to [wrap a tool](http://docs.rabix.io/tutorial-1-wrapping-samtools-sort) in a docker container.

In the linked tutorial page, step 2 describes how to create the container

```
$ docker run -ti ubuntu
```

and

```
root@70235f7726cf:/#
```

I install a number of libraries/programs

```
$ apt-get install wget build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev
[...]
```

then

```
exit
```

Step 3 describes how the docker container is saved into an image but there is only the procedure to save it in a private repo and not in docker hub.
I did some research and the following is the command to push an image to a Docker repository in the Hub

```
$ docker push myusr/my-repo:mytoolv1
```

but since I did not save the image the push does not work.
The tutorial I'm following is missing some steps in between or maybe it is me that is missing some knowledge of Docker.

Comment: "*I do not know how to do it.*" Does the `docker push` command not meet your requirements? Can you provide a bit more detail/specificity around why it doesn't in accordance with [ask]?

Comment: I did some changes, hope it is more clear

Comment: You might find the official Docker [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial a better overview.  The `docker commit` sequence your linked page described really isn't a best practice.

Comment: @DavidMaze: the tutorial I was following is really messed up for what concerns the Docker image creation and push to docker repo. Thank to your linked tutorial and to the answers I've got I was able to reach my goal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have some terms mixed up. You can't push containers to dockerhub, you can only push images.

To create a custom image you need a Dockerfile. Something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y wget build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev

...
```

Then from the same folder build the custom image by running

```sh
docker build -t myusr/my-repo:mytoolv1 .
```

Ath thus point you can push the image to dockerhub using the command you tried:

```sh
docker push myusr/my-repo:mytoolv1
```

Comment: I successfully build && push my image to the docker hub. Thank you for your constructive support

Answer (score 1):

What is in your mind and is not correct, is that you think you can push **container** to your local repo, but in fact you are pushing the **image**.

I hope you know the difference between an image and a container, if not you can search about.

You can create a file called `Dockerfile` (with no extension and with this exact name) with the following contents:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# to set time zone as you may encounter some unexpected stuck when selecting time zone during the build
ENV TZ=Asia/Tehran # search more about it in https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev
```

Now you should build your image:

```
docker build -t yourrepo/NAME:TAG_VERSION .
```

example:

```
docker build -t yourrepo/my_image:1.0.0 .
```

Now you can push it:

```
docker push yourrepo/my_image:1.0.0
```

Comment: the docker build command should include a directory at the end, like this it would not work. Change it to `docker build -t yourrepo/NAME:TAG_VERSION .`

Comment: @MatteoZanoni you're right, thanks. I didn't notice that doesn't exist